# Updating Confluent Schema Registry in Dataflow, Apache Beam

Tags: python, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, confluent-schema-registry

I have an Apache Beam pipeline built in Python that sends and reads from Kafka topics orchestrated via Dataflow.
I would like to use the Python components [apache_beam.io.kafka.WriteToKafka](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.32.0/apache_beam.io.kafka.html#apache_beam.io.kafka.WriteToKafka) and [apache_beam.io.kafka.ReadFromKafka](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.32.0/apache_beam.io.kafka.html#apache_beam.io.kafka.ReadFromKafka) while accessing and updating (Confluent) Schema Registry for sending and reading `protobuf` messages.

In Java it is possible to achieve [this](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.22.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html):

```
 PCollection<KafkaRecord<Long, GenericRecord>> input = pipeline
   .apply(KafkaIO.<Long, GenericRecord>read()
      .withBootstrapServers("broker_1:9092,broker_2:9092")
      .withTopic("my_topic")
      .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
      // Use Confluent Schema Registry, specify schema registry URL and value subject
      .withValueDeserializer(
          ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of("http://localhost:8081", "my_topic-value"))
    ...
```

I tried to specify the value `value_serializer` by passing the class `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer` like this:

```
...
| "Write to Kafka topic" >> WriteToKafka(
    producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': servers},
    topic=topic,
    key_serializer="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
    value_serializer="io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer"
)
...
```

But I am having the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denes/experiments/protobuf/send_proto_to_kafka.py", line 144, in <module>
    run_pipeline(project_id=project_id,
  File "/home/denes/experiments/protobuf/send_proto_to_kafka.py", line 99, in run_pipeline
    (p
  File "/home/denes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 137, in __or__
    return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
  File "/home/denes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 640, in apply
    return self.apply(
  File "/home/denes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 651, in apply
    return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/home/denes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 694, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
  File "/home/denes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 185, in apply
    return m(transform, input, options)
  File "/home/denes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 215, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/home/denes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 297, in expand
    raise RuntimeError(response.error)
RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build transform beam:external:java:kafka:write:v1 from spec urn: "beam:external:java:kafka:write:v1"
payload: "\n\200\001\n\035\n\017producer_config...p.b-test6org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer?io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer"

    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$ExternalTransformRegistrarLoader.lambda$knownTransforms$0(ExpansionService.java:140)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$TransformProvider.apply(ExpansionService.java:367)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:470)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:546)
    at org.apache.beam.model.expansion.v1.ExpansionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ExpansionServiceGrpc.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO.resolveClass(KafkaIO.java:2839)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO.access$300(KafkaIO.java:527)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO$Write$Builder.buildExternal(KafkaIO.java:2558)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO$Write$Builder.buildExternal(KafkaIO.java:2541)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$ExternalTransformRegistrarLoader.lambda$knownTransforms$0(ExpansionService.java:135)
    ... 12 more
```

Note that it is possible to solve [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/protobuf_producer.py) without using Apache Beam.

Comment: It looks like you need to create a custom expansion service that includes KafkaProtobufSerializer in its classpath. By default I don't think it's included in the Java expansion service. I'll see if I can find more info on how to add the dependency to a custom expansion service and use it.

Comment: Thanks @DanielOliveira, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, any jars you add to classpath when starting the expansion service will be available to (and will be staged by) Dataflow. So that should resolve the "Could not find class" error.

Comment: See here for information on starting up an expansion service: http://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#create-x-lang-transforms

Comment: Thanks @chamikara for the link. Not sure whether it will work with the ``io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer`` or not. Basically I want to create a custom serializer out of this class.
The docs says that I have to start the expansion service. Is it possible to start it via Dataflow?

Comment: So looking at "KafkaProtobufSerializer" seems like it produces a Java object "com.google.protobuf.Message". I don't think you can get this through the Python API since Python is unaware of this object (and won't be able to encode it). Will you be OK with getting the Kafka messages as proto bytes and perform a deserialization to produce Python objects in a subsequent ParDo in Python side ?

Comment: @chamikara, I was able to send Kafka messages as proto bytes. However I want to update the confluent schema registry as well with the operation apache_beam.io.kafka.WriteToKafka.